# How to install and configure the imaginebundle in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I searched in google but I disappoint that I could not get any satisfactory answer any where. How to install and configure the imaginebundle in symfony2. I have try several times as per instruction given in https://github.com/moreweb/ImagineBundle. Still I am not getting any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle you linked to does not look like it's maintained anymore - [this](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) seems to be the correct bundle.

The new KnpIpsum demo site uses it and you can see their configuration [here](http://ipsum.knplabs.com/avalanche-imagine) or alternatively download the source code of the demo app from github: [KnpIpsum](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpIpsum-for-symfony)

Comment: My intention is that I want to generate a thumbnail image and save in a separate directory.

Comment: Yes, this bundle will do that. It's the one you want